# Yes/ No : Is $ u(x,1) = \begin{cases} 1 \text{ if } |x| < 2 \\ 0 , \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $u(x,t)$  be the solution  of the wave  equation

$\frac{∂^2u}{∂t^2} =\frac{∂^2u}{∂x^2} ,x \in \mathbb{R}$, $t > 0$

$u(x, 0) = u_0(x) ,x \in \mathbb{R}$

$\frac{∂u}{∂t} (x, 0) = 0 ,x \in \mathbb{R}$

Let $u_0(x)$  be the  function function defined  by

$$ u_0(x)   = \begin{cases} 1 \text{ if } |x| < 2 \\ 0 , \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Compute $u(x,1)$ at all points $x \in \mathbb{R} $where it is  continious

My attempt : using 
D'Alembert's formula: $$u(x,1) = \frac{(1+1) +(1-1)}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\int_{1-1}^{1+1}0\,{\rm d}s = 1.$$

Now  $$ u(x,1)   = \begin{cases} 1 \text{ if } |x| < 2 \\ 0 , \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Is  its  true ?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite.

$$u(x, t) = \frac{1}{2} (u_0(x+ct) + u_0(x-ct)) = \frac{1}{2}(1_{[-2,2]}(x+ct)+1_{[-2,2]}(x-ct))$$

since the initial time derivative is zero. Here, $c=0$ and $t=1$, giving

$$u(x, 1) = \frac{1}{2}(1_{[-2,2]}(x+1) + 1_{[-2,2]}(x-1)).$$

These pieces simplify to $1_{[-3,1]}(x)$ and $1_{[-1,3]}(x)$, respectively.

Think about what waves do physically. They spread out in both directions. That intuition would tell you your solution was possibly wrong. When your time derivative initial condition is zero, you can imagine your initial waveform as being two waves with the exact same profile only at half the amplitude that then move in opposite directions as you move forward in time.